Access Token Not Retained in WebView When Opening via Deep Link in React Native #3621
Bug description:
I am encountering an issue with WebView in my React Native app. When the application is launched using a deep link, the WebView does not retain the access token, causing the user to be logged out. However, when logging in directly using credentials within the app, everything works as expected.
Setup:
Dependencies:
"@react-native-cookies/cookies": "6.0.11"
"react-native-webview": "13.10.5"
What I've Tried:
Passing cookies using CookieManager.
Verifying that the access token is set correctly when logging in directly.
Expected Behavior:
The WebView should retain the access token and maintain the session when launched via a deep link.
Actual Behavior:
The WebView does not recognize the access token, resulting in an automatic logout.
Additional Context:
Any insights or suggestions on ensuring cookies persist in WebView when using deep links would be greatly appreciated.
<WebView 
  ref={(ref) => { this.webviewRef = ref; }}
  key={this.state.key}
  onLoad={() => this.hideLoader()}
  source={{ uri: this.state.source }}
  androidHardwareAccelerationDisabled={true}
  androidLayerType="software"
  sharedCookiesEnabled={true}
  thirdPartyCookiesEnabled={true}
  useSharedProcessPool={true}
  incognito={false}
  domStorageEnabled={true}
  cacheEnabled={false}
  useWebKit={true}
  style={{ opacity: 0.99 }}
  clearHistory={true}
  javaScriptEnabled
  onNavigationStateChange={this._onNavigationStateChange.bind(this)}
  onMessage={this.onMessage.bind(this)}
/>

